# Is Sleep option available in karate? I was trying to delete a variable from json file after specific period of time(ex: 1 min) using karate script

Tags: karate

I am new to karate. I was trying to find out how to delete a variable from a JSON file after a specific period of time say, for example, I want to wait for 1 min before deleting the variable and then perform Delete operation using the Delete keyword(can we do this with the help of sleep option or there is any other way to do?)
Can anyone suggest to me how I can write a script for this?